# What rendering technology is GrabCad Mobile App using?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, 3d, visualization

I am wondering what kind of rendering engine is GrabCAD using for visualization purpose for it mobile apps. The 3d models are rendered very nicely.

They have rolled out both iOS and Android apps.

My hunch is that they have built the viewer directly on top of openGL but if they are using any commercial engine like HOOPS or something else it would be great to know.